# error QTcreator using ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python3, qt-creator

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/123/Documents/untitled1/widget.py", line 6, in <module>
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
ImportError: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: undefined symbol: _dl_vsym, version GLIBC_PRIVATE
19:45:44: /usr/bin/python3 exited with code 1
```

code:
This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide6.QtCore import QFile
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "form.ui"
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: please provide use some specifications about the context of your error code

Comment: Is this QtCreator as a snap?  If so you need to contact the snap creator and indicate you have a bug there, there's not much *we* can do to fix that since everything's snapped and sandboxed.